# How can I find an unfinished build when I can't remember where I built it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a Minecraft map,and I seem to have lost one of the unfinished builds in the map. I've looked everywhere I can but I can't find it. Is there a way to track down the coordinates of the build? I did use structure blocks if that's any help. I can track it down myself but I need to know a way to do so. Other useful info could be that I use Windows not Mac, and I am running Minecraft 1.12.Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you have used unique blocks, you may want to try using a MCEdit type program and searching for those specific blocks.

Comment: Or if it was near your spawn, you can use a compass to get near it.

Comment: that sounds like good advice but I don't use mods because they might crash or corrupt my game so I don't even have MC Edit. and the structure isn't anywhere near my spawn

Comment: Setting the game mode to creative (press t than: /gamemode creative ) and flying around might be the easiest in game solution as far as I know, just make a backup before you start flying. On the other hand, MCEdit is not a mod, it is separate program. Just like WorldPainter. If you open your wolrd in any of these programs you will see the map with the already generated chunks (Worldpainter gives a map, and MCEdit gives a more "Minecraft like" interface). I hope I could help! 
Ps: Always make a backup of the save game before you open it any external program

Comment: Guest, as far as I know. Mods and Mc-edit etc **does not**  crash or corrupt your game(that is if the mod is not fraudulent). But trusted mods just require something like forge or technic launcher to work. Whilst on the other hand, MC-edit it a standalone software, it is not installed into your game. It just has the capacity to change your 'saves' folder. As long as you are not editing in Minecraft and editing in MC-Edit, you should be fine..

Comment: @KingsleyZhong And if you are really worried about accidentally modifying or corrupting your world, you can always just copy it from windows file explorer and open the copy with MC-edit.

Comment: @Malco Your RIght

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this. Believe me, I've tried. Unless maybe you used a map to see a wide area around you, but other than that, the only solution is MCEdit, or WorldPainter.

Answer (score 0):

there are ways...

safest way (not that there is anything unsafe about mods, if you know where to get them from) is to use mapping software - external programs which will read your save data and generate a huge png image showing areas you have explored. once you have the map you should be able to recognize any structures (assuming they are large enough and on the surface).

mcedit isn't safe because it's complicated and original poster doesn't sound very savvy. let's skip that one. it's a great thing but it can destroy worlds.

nbt-editors (even better - nbt viewers) can be used to get coordinates of explored chunks; if the original poster writes down most remote explored chunks and teleports into them, he might recognize (or bump into) his fort/lighthouse/whatever (just write down first; world save file will change).

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading worldpainter, import your world, note your co-ordinate, and teleport to them.

Answer (score -2):

Make a map. I don't know other way than to just explore. Instead of `/gamemode creative`, use `/gamemode 1` or `/gamemode c`.

Comment: Needs more detail